# Why won't SDL 2.0 give me an OpenGL ES 2.0 window?

Tags: opengles, sdl

I have a small SDL 2.0 program (detailed below) that refuses to give me a window, complaining about not being able to initialize its OpenGL ES library.

Program:

```
#include "bcm_host.h"

#include <SDL.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
        bcm_host_init();

        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0, 0, 400, 300, 0);
        if (window == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Could not initialize OpenGL / GLES library
```

What's going on?  Shouldn't `bcm_host_init()` be all that I need to get a normal SDL 2.0 program to run on the Pi?  What else do I need to do?

Comment: I have the same error (I don't use bcm_host_init function). The code is compiled right in my raspberry, but I cannot run it. Best regards

Comment: Do you have at least `gpu_mem=128` in `/boot/config.txt` to allow for 3D acceleration?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the culprit was mesa-common-dev. Try removing it using

```
% sudo apt-get remove mesa-common-dev
```

A new round of ./configure && make && sudo make install made my SDL2 program run.

Comment: Thanks @Johan-Kanflo for your answer. I had similar problem with Urho3D on RPi 3, which your answer solved it. Thanks.